# The right way to handle adding new mini-features to a feature, which branch has already been merged into master

Tags: git

I don't have too much experience working with git and currently I'm using the local one in `Xcode 9`. I would like to understand the following:
Let's say we have two features to implement, called `feature1` and `feature2`.

Now, to handle the `feature1` we create a new branch from the `master`, called `feature1_branch`. After successfully implementing that feature, we merge it back into the `master`.

Then, we create a new branch for the `feature2`, called `feature2_branch`. Now, we have successfully implemented it, but haven't merged it back into the `master`, and we suddenly realise that there is a mini-feature to be added to `feature1`.

So, what is the right policy here: should we merge `feature2` into the `master` and create a new branch for that mini-feature, called `feature1.1_branch`, or should we branch from `feature2_branch` and create a new one for the mini-feature?

I believe that the second way isn't the right one, because I think intuitively that new branches, created from the existing one, should somehow be related to it, but `feature1.1` has nothing to do with `feature2`. But if this case isn't too wrong and we can follow it, how we could merge `feature1.1_branch` back? I mean, should we first merge it into `feature2_branch` or directly into the `master` branch?

I would appreciate some explanation for this cases from you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any shared code?

Comment: @BagusTesa, This is a theoretical question. I'm not sure that you need a code to answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `feature1_branch` has been merged into master–which means it's now a permanent part of your code base, you shouldn't branch `feature1.1` off it. Just branch off `master` like it is a complete new feature that has nothing to do with `feature1` (`feature1.1` and `feature2` then become 2 parallel branches).

From what you describe, `feature1.1` and `feature2` are quite unrelated. It should be then easy to merge them back. This is similar to having two people working in parallel on different parts of the project: if their work are completely separate, they can just merge them back into `master` whenever they are done; there should be none or very little conflicts.

It is certainly wrong to branch it off `feature2_branch`.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. So, conflicts occur when the same part of code is changed from different branches and they are merged to the master one (but not necessarily merged at the same time), right?

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan Precisely 

Comment: But let's imagine that you need to change some implementation of a feature that was already merged into the master (change, not to add a new one). So, won't there be a conflict in that case?

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan From git's point of view, there are really no difference between "change an existing feature" and "add a new feature": they are both just changes to the code base. In both cases, you branch off from `master`, implement the changes, and merge.

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan If you are making change to a feature that has already been merged to master, there can't be any conflict because you branched off from `master` (where the feature was already there!). It is a  bit like you continue to modify the feature after it has completed. There are no parallel changes, so there are no conflicts.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thank you for explaining all that stuff to me!